# Why does plt.figure(figsize) render different results when plotting pd.DataFrame and pd.Series?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

In the two snippets below, where the only difference seems to be the datasource type (`pd.Series` vs `pd.DataFrame`), does `plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 3), dpi=80)` have an effect in one case but not in the other when using [pd.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)?

---

**Snippet 1 - Adjusting plot size when data is a pandas Series**

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10000),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10000)).cumsum()
print(type(df))

# plot
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 3), dpi=80)
ax = df.plot()
plt.show()
```

**Output 1**
[image]

**Snippet 2 - Now the data source is a pandas Dataframe**

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(123)
dfx = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100)).cumsum()
dfy = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100)).cumsum()
df = pd.concat([dfx, dfy], axis = 1)
print(type(df))

# plot
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 3), dpi=80)
ax = df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The only difference here seems to be the type of the datasource. Why would that have something to say for the matplotlib output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `pd.Dataframe.plot()` works a bit differently from `pd.Series.plot()`. Since the dataframe might have any number of columns, which might require subplots, different axes, etc., Pandas defaults to creating a new `figure`. The way around this is to feed the arguments directly to the `plot` call, ie, `df.plot(figsize=(12, 3))` (`dpi` isn't accepted as a keyword-argument, unfortunately). You can read more about in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42220582):

> In the first case, you create a matplotlib figure via fig =
>   plt.figure(figsize=(10,4)) and then plot a single column DataFrame.
>   Now the internal logic of pandas plot function is to check if there is
>   already a figure present in the matplotlib state machine, and if so,
>   use it's current axes to plot the columns values to it. This works as
>   expected.
>
> However in the second case, the data consists of two columns. There
>   are several options how to handle such a plot, including using
>   different subplots with shared or non-shared axes etc. In order for
>   pandas to be able to apply any of those possible requirements, it will
>   by default create a new figure to which it can add the axes to plot
>   to. The new figure will not know about the already existing figure and
>   its size, but rather have the default size, unless you specify the
>   figsize argument.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Your suggestion works beautifully! I'm a bit baffled that I didn't find the link you provided myself, because I sure tried. So I guess it's time to bring out the dupe hammer, although my question perhaps is a tiny bit more specific.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm not sure it's exactly a dupe - I'll leave it to the mods to decide.