# How do you resize a bar chart created using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've found other topics similar to this, but I'm finding anything that works specifically for me, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

I've got the following code:

```
# Plot weather vs. # of accidents on grouped-bar-chart for each year
data_chart = dataset2.plot.bar()
data_chart.set_xlabel('Weather Condition')
data_chart.set_ylabel('No. of Accidents')
data_chart.set_title('Annual Number of Accidents per Weather Condition')
```

I've tried using the two following bits of code to increase the size of my chart:

```
data_chart.plot(figsize=(10,5))

plt.figure(figsize=[10,5])
```

but neither of them have worked.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))`, `dataset2.plot.bar(ax=ax)`.

Comment: Calling `plt.figure(figsize=[10,5])` after you created the plot just creates a new plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistency when setting figure size using pandas plot method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215252/inconsistency-when-setting-figure-size-using-pandas-plot-method)

Comment: Thanks, but I just get ```NameError: name 'ax' is not defined.```  Do I need to import something special to use ax?

Comment: Please see my answer and check if it works. If it doesn't let me know I will help.

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
import matplotlib .pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,5)
data_chart = dataset2.plot.bar()
data_chart.set_xlabel('Weather Condition')
data_chart.set_ylabel('No. of Accidents')
data_chart.set_title('Annual Number of Accidents per Weather Condition')
plt.show()
```

Matplot lib defaults `**to width, height in inches=[6.4, 4.8]**`. set as `rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [6.4, 4.8]`. So Change them to `(10,5)`